# I have some kind of virus

Tags: virus, malware, adware

I have a problem with some kind of malware?(or another kind of virus), I cant get rid of it, heres some info i figured out, I hope that someone could actually help me : This virus is in my computer corrupting my browsers, i did some bad download in google chrome, but the virus actually infected all the browsers I have and also for some reason downloaded mozzila firefox and added to my quickbar.
- I am using win 10

Virus does :
- Changing browser search engine, homepage
- Adds a lot of ads
- Sometime shutting down browser for fun
- Maybe editing/creating windows registers? ( not confirmed )
- cannot change my default apps 
- adding search engine into browser called : Search123 ( or something like that )

I think that it is something more than just some basic adware, because i have experience with it and it is easily removable, because it has some name and you just delete it, but this kind of virus is something bigger, it adds ads from many "pages" , so i think that this is some SUPERmalware, because it possibly consists of many adware viruses. I tried few apps to delete it,but didnt work out, I tried some basic anti adware/malware apps, Avast antivirus, windows firewall thing, Avira antivirus and few more, nothing did work.

Could please someone help me? this thing makes me mad alot, and i dont know how to fight it.

Comment: Since you don't even know what exactly it is and by the kind you are asking it seems your not really a PC-literate Person. I would strongly recommend you to bring your PC to a computer scientist or at least someone who has way more Experience than you and let him check your PC. (don't take this as rude or offensive against you, it's just better to let such things be done by Professionals)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to download both rkill and malwarebytes to your system.

run rkill so it can end any malicious processes then run malwarebytes to help clean it up (hopefully). if that doesnt work then i would say your best bet is to re-image the computer and start with a clean os.

good luck and god speed.

-Grimm

Comment: Adwcleaner from Malwarebytes is also very useful, particularly in an Adware and Browser Hijacking case like this.